# Share ViewModels between fragments OR share LiveData between ViewModels

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Basically I want a way to **properly** share ViewModels between fragments OR share LiveData between ViewModels.

**My scenario:**

I have 2 fragments (`FragmentA` & `FragmentB`) - each has its own ViewModels:

`FragmentA` has `ViewModelA`, `FragmentB` has `ViewModelB`.

`ViewModelA` has `LiveDataA1`, `ViewModelB` has `LiveDataB1` and `LiveDataB2`

`ViewModelB` is only allowed to have `LiveDataB2` and `ViewModelA` cannot have it.

**Problem** is I want `FragmentA` to observe `LiveDataB2` from `ViewModelB`.

**Approach#1:**

Aside from `ViewModelA`, `ViewModelB` is also be used in `FragmentA` (so it's like 2 ViewModels in FragmentA).
So `FragmentA` will observe `LiveDataB2` from `ViewModelB`.

This is my current implementation now. But I feel like it's not proper to have another ViewModel that is intended for other fragments.
I thinking that each Fragment should only have 1 ViewModel.

**Approach#2:**

Create a new `SharedViewModel`.
So we will have 3 ViewModels now:
`ViewModelA` has `LiveDataA1`, `ViewModelB` has `LiveDataB1`, `SharedViewModel` has `LiveDataB2`.
(Here I move `LiveDataB2` from `ViewModelB` to `SharedViewModel`)

Aside from `ViewModelA`, `SharedViewModel` is also be used in `FragmentA`.
So FragmentA will observe `LiveDataB2` from `SharedViewModel`.

So I guess its the same as #1 but I guess but here I'm thinking that `SharedViewModel` is just a util ViewModel to just like get the shared data needed.
So here we are like putting all the LiveDatas that can be common/shared between FragmentA and FragmentB (or even with other fragments)

**Approach#3:**

Share LiveData between ViewModels.
I think this is wild and I don't know how to implement this.
But I'm thinking that there will a new `LiveDataA2` in `ViewModelA` that **refers to the same instance** as `LiveDataB2` in `ViewModelB`.

So `FragmentA` will only have `ViewModelA` and can observe `LiveDataA2`.
If there is a change in `LiveDataB2` in `ViewModelB`, `FragmentA` will have it.

**Badly need some advise here on which the proper way!**

Comment: IMHO Approach#2 is the best way to observe Livedata from multiple Fragments

Comment: I'm not sure if it bad practice or not, but I've successfully implemented your first approach, with multiple fragments having multiple SharedViewModels, even 5 fragments using the same ViewModel instance and a single fragment using up to 3 ViewModel instances, without any isssue so far.

Answer (score 0):

[Shared ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) is the right approach

You should use a single `Shared ViewModel` for both fragments `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` with multiple live data objects `LiveDataA1`,  `LiveDataB1` and `LiveDataB2`, with this approach your `FragmentA` can easily observe `LiveDataB2`.

Now, the problem with your approaches are:

**Approach#1:**

If `FragmentA` creates an instance of `ViewModelB` you  will not get `ViewModelB` associate with `FragmentB` so `ViewModelB` lost its state.

**Approach#2:**

Somehow the problem is you are creating separate `ViewModel` when there is a recommended way i.e `Shared ViewModel` as per official docs

**Approach#3:**

Sharing `LiveData` objects is not the right approach as it is associated with lifecycle owner.

Comment: [If FragmentA creates an instance of ViewModelB you will not get ViewModelB associate with FragmentB so ViewModelB lost its state] 
In this case, ViewModelB is shared.

My approach#2 is already using the recommended way

Comment: @iori24 yeah, you can go with it, if there is no need for other viewmodels then you should only use `Shared ViewModel`